# Is it possible render video frames directly to AirPlay from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, airplay, cmsamplebuffer

Is it possible for me to generate `CMSampleBuffers` in real time and stream that to a TV via AirPlay. Similarly to how I am able to render those frames directly to an `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` on the iOS device.

I know that I can use AirPlay with the HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) protocol, but, like I mentioned, in my case, the video is being generated on the actual iOS device and thus, I want to stream it in "real time" to AirPlay.

For Audio it appears to be doable with `AVSampleBufferRenderSynchronizer` and `AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer` (as outlined in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/streaming_and_airplay/supporting_airplay_in_your_app). But, can't find any info in regards to video.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet but I think iOS17 might have added support for this via AVSampleBufferVideoRenderer.

The docs are very sparse but it exists publicly at least, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avsamplebuffervideorenderer

Comment: That's great info. Thanks for letting me know, I will look into it later and see what I can figure out!

Comment: @Anton I’m curios, did that end up working?

Comment: @sym3tri No, it was not possible (at least not at the time). Was unfortunately not able to render to AirPlay with AVSampleBufferVideoRenderer. That said, AVSampleBufferVideoRenderer does in fact seem to work great for other purposes. It was fairly easy to get it working for regular video playback.